# Run-Time error '438' "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I get the '438' error and when i Debug, the following line is highlighted yellow

```
If (Sheet4.Cells(i, j).ColorIndex <> xlNone) Then
```

I can't find the reason why I get this error. Is it syntax error? Or is it a bigger problem? I need to see or change colors of a Cell many times in my code.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) does not have a .ColorIndex property. However, its .Interior or possibly its .Font can have a .ColorIndex. To check whether the Fill of a cell is colored, you can check the .Pattern against **xlNone**.

```
'for Fill
If Sheet4.Cells(i, j).Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then
'for Font
If Sheet4.Cells(i, j).Font.ColorIndex <> xlAutomatic Then
```

Checking the font colorindex against xlColorIndexAutomatic might be a better approach. Your question is lacking some specifics.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped that solves it. Syntax error thank God. :)